# CSS pseudo-element to apply the first character of an element

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have the following content in my h1 tag: "(Hello World)" so I add the following to my css to change the first character of this element:

```
h1:first-letter { font-size:63px; color:#510007; font-family:Helvetica; }
```

But, as I noticed, first-letter is only for letters, so is there any workarounds to apply this style to the first char? Which in this case is "(".

Comment: Actually the result aren't what I expected as the 2 first characters go big! http://jsfiddle.net/Bk5M8/ Like BoltClock said, If the first char is a punctuation then the letter next to it will be applied the style too. If the first character is a letter then, this is the only one that's gonna be affected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-letter):

> Punctuation (i.e, characters defined in Unicode [[UNICODE]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-UNICODE) in the "open" (Ps), "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po) punctuation classes), that precedes or follows the first letter should be included

So your bracket *and* the letter H are selected by `:first-letter`, because `(` is considered a punctuation symbol, not a letter.

There are two workarounds:

1. Wrap your opening bracket in `span` tags:

   ```html
   <!-- To style both (), wrap both in <span> tags -->
   <h1><span>(</span>Hello World)</h1>
   ```

   and target `h1 span`:

   ```css
   h1 span {
       font-size: 63px;
       color: #510007;
       font-family: Helvetica;
   }
   ```
2. Drop the brackets from your text:

   ```html
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   ```

   and use `:before` and/or `:after` instead (not supported in IE7 and older):

   ```css
   /* To style both (), use h1:before, h1:after */
   h1:before {
       font-size: 63px;
       color: #510007;
       font-family: Helvetica;
   }

   h1:before { content: '('; }
   h1:after { content: ')'; }
   ```

Comment: Any solutions to this problems without touching the HTML. Which in my case can not be modified?

Comment: @Esser: What Boldewyn said.

Comment: @BoltClock my question was if there's a fix for the CSS method as I would try to avoid using javascript when it's doable with CSS. But thanks.