# Is there a way to select the first character? :first-letter does not seem to work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Example problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6WYXk/

I have some html: `<p>% hello world</p>`

I want to make the % bold. To do this usually I would write this in CSS:

```
p:first-letter
{
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

However that makes the % *and the* h bold.

Ideally I'd like a psudeo selector of `:first-character`

Comment: +1 interesting problem +

Comment: Interesting the browser would consider "% h" as a letter.

Comment: In fact it seems to be browser-dependent - Firefox doesn't make anything bold, Chrome and Safari make "% h" bold. Only Opera successfully made the "%" only bold. (don't know for IE, it went into some compatibility mode and couldn't render the jsfiddle page at all :)

Comment: Would you believe me if I said IE9 seems to behave correctly?

Comment: Fascinating. Chrome and Safari (i.e., webkit) are the only ones to get it right according to the spec (`%` is of unicode character class `Po` — other punctuation — and the CSS spec says that preceding punctuation, including that class, should also match against `:first-letter`). Well probably; it's not clear whether the space (class `Zs`) should change things. I'm certainly not convinced that Opera gets it right, but Firefox arguably does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, that's odd. Doesn't work for other symbol chars as well and the same problem has been discussed [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649296/css-pseudo-element-to-apply-the-first-character-of-an-element) as well.

You should try something like this:

```html
<p>hello world</p>
```

```css
p:before { content:"%"; font-weight: bold; padding-right: 5px;}
```

​
[Try it yourself…](http://jsfiddle.net/6WYXk/25/)

Comment: Beat me to finding the reference to [the `:first-letter` spec definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter), though I'm having trouble finding direct reference to these character classes. (namely "open" (Ps), "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po) punctuation classes, from the spec)

Comment: @Nightfirecat The definitive version is at http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt but be aware that it's over a megabyte of plain text and not very easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your can write like this:

```
<p><span>%</span> hello world</p>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6WYXk/30/